# Doesn't Azure AD have a metadata document that lists the `issuer` for v1 access tokens?

Tags: security, azure-active-directory, jwt, openid-connect, entra

The OpenID Connect metadata document for an Azure tenant is:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`

It lists the `issuer` to be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/v2.0"`.

However, that's only the case when using v2 access tokens. For v1 access tokens the `issuer` is actually `https://sts.windows.net/<tenant-id>/`, which causes applications, that fully depend on the metadata document, to fail.

Doesn't Azure AD have a metadata document that lists the `issuer` for v1 access tokens?

Note: I know it's generally possible to specify `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,` in the manifest to use v2 access token with expected `issuer`, but that's not an option here